# C++20: A question about dynamic exception specification

Tags: c++, exception, dynamic, c++20, specifications

Reference: [Dynamic exception specification (until C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec)

I am writing some test code and would like to specify a throw exception of type `std::bad_alloc` ([std::bad_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)) for a template function, which would try and allocate memory dynamically for the merge of two sorted arrays of type T:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
std::unique_ptr<std::array<T,N>>merge2SortedArrays(std::array<std::array<T,N>,2>) throw(bad_alloc);
```

The objective is that the user of the function template should know that a `bad_alloc` exception could result if memory allocation fails, and should have a corresponding catch block in the invoking code to handle this.

I am using `g++` for compilation and using the compile-time flag `-std=c++20`.

In the link related to dynamic exception specification above, it has been stated that this construct is only supported until C++17.

So is there an alternative in C++20? Or could we continue using the construct?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) specifier:

- `noexcept(false)` would specify a potentially throwing function.
- `noexcept(true)` or just `noexcept` would specify a non-throwing function.

Other than through documentation, it's not possible to specify *what* exception type a function may throw. It's either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Is it possible to specify that the function would only throw bad_alloc? Or only that it would or would not throw exception? If the latter, how would the invoking code handle that exception? I understand that a catch-all is considered bad design practice?

Comment: @Vinod I added an answer to that to the answer.

Comment: @Vinod Why specifically does the caller need to handle the exception? If there is some specific way it can handle a specific exceptional situation, then it should catch that exception. Any other exception can be handled further up the stack. If you need to catch the exception only because some cleanup is necessary, then `catch(...)` followed by re-throw (`throw;`) is fine. In general it is a good idea to assume that any C++ code can throw any exception at any time, which is why writing exception-safe code is so important (e.g. no raw `new`).

Comment: @Vinod Also, just as a side note: On many OS it is not safe to rely on `std::bad_alloc` for memory overuse. On e.g. Linux overallocation is default and your program will simply get a SIGSEGV if you try to access more memory than is free. Even if that is not the case on your OS, `std::bad_alloc` can usually not be handled in any meaningful way and letting it escape to terminate the program isn't a bad choice.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for that; what can be another meaningful way of handling bad_alloc than termination, if you have run out of memory?

Comment: @Vinod Depends on what your application does. Maybe it can free some memory and then retry the operation. It would be something specific to your application.